# Using the right selector in jQuery to not need to duplicate code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have question regarding selectors in jQuery. If you look at my fiddle. I need to duplicate the same lines of jQuery for it to react to every icon. I'm sure I only need line 1-6 but instead using better selectors. And, if I would need to use the same icon-section 2 times on the same page it would interfere with each other. Does anybody have some advice?

```js
$( ".icon:nth-child(1)" ).click(function() {
    $( ".icon" ).removeClass( "selected" );
    $( ".icon:nth-child(1)" ).toggleClass( "selected" );
    $( ".text" ).fadeOut().delay( 500 );
  $( ".text:nth-child(1)" ).fadeIn();
});
$( ".icon:nth-child(2)" ).click(function() {
    $( ".icon" ).removeClass( "selected" );
    $( ".icon:nth-child(2)" ).toggleClass( "selected" );
  $( ".text" ).fadeOut().delay( 500 );
  $( ".text:nth-child(2)" ).fadeIn();
});
$( ".icon:nth-child(3)" ).click(function() {
    $( ".icon" ).removeClass( "selected" );
    $( ".icon:nth-child(3)" ).toggleClass( "selected" );
  $( ".text" ).fadeOut().delay( 500 );
  $( ".text:nth-child(3)" ).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon,
.icon img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.text {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="icons">
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png">
            <p>
            Button 1
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png">
            <p>
            Button 2
            </p>
        </div>        
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png">
            <p>
            Button 3
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="texts">
            <div class="text hidden">
                <p>
                    Text 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo tenetur quos quisquam, in totam dolorem enim nostrum nihil impedit ducimus beatae, eos obcaecati ratione voluptatum recusandae incidunt, quas labore doloremque.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text hidden">
                <p>
                    Text 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo tenetur quos quisquam, in totam dolorem enim nostrum nihil impedit ducimus beatae, eos obcaecati ratione voluptatum recusandae incidunt, quas labore doloremque.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text hidden">
                <p>
                    Text 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo tenetur quos quisquam, in totam dolorem enim nostrum nihil impedit ducimus beatae, eos obcaecati ratione voluptatum recusandae incidunt, quas labore doloremque.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

[jsFiddle - Icontoggle](https://jsfiddle.net/gustavgesar/2bv4seh1/33/)

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this)!

```
$( ".icon" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "selected" );
});
```

Comment: ... and the main part of the logic which controls displaying the related `.text` elements?

Comment: I just gave the hint. He better use $(this). This is very easy task and he should handle it himself!

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to jQuery. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make this more DRY you can relate the clicked `.icon` element to the `.text` by their `index()`, like this:

```
$(".icon").click(function() {
  $(".icon").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".text").fadeOut().delay(500).eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
});
```

Using this method means you don't need to repeat your JS code at all, and can have an infinite number of `.icon`/`.text` element.s

```js
$(".icon").click(function() {
  $(".icon").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".text").fadeOut().delay(500).eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon,
.icon img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
}

.icon p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

.text {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="icons">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png">
      <p>
        Button 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png">
      <p>
        Button 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png">
      <p>
        Button 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="texts">
    <div class="text hidden">
      <p>
        Text 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo tenetur quos quisquam, in totam dolorem enim nostrum nihil impedit ducimus beatae, eos obcaecati ratione voluptatum recusandae incidunt, quas labore doloremque.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text hidden">
      <p>
        Text 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo tenetur quos quisquam, in totam dolorem enim nostrum nihil impedit ducimus beatae, eos obcaecati ratione voluptatum recusandae incidunt, quas labore doloremque.

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text hidden">
      <p>
        Text 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo tenetur quos quisquam, in totam dolorem enim nostrum nihil impedit ducimus beatae, eos obcaecati ratione voluptatum recusandae incidunt, quas labore doloremque.

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've used your advice in [JSFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/gustavgesar/2bv4seh1/86/) and tried to make the "slideUp" to happen first and then the "removeClass" and so on but it doesn't seem to work. Another issue is that if I click on the same icon that is already selected, the .delay works but not in the other cases. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `each()` method with indexing:

```
$( ".icon" ).each(function(index, elem){
    $(elem).on('click', function(){
        $( ".icon" ).removeClass( "selected" ).eq(index).toggleClass( "selected" );
        $( ".text" ).fadeOut().delay( 500 ).eq(index).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Live jsBin [here](https://jsbin.com/finacoweki/edit?js,output).